# A simple inequality...or not?

Tags: inequality

I came upon this question,

> $\frac1x<\frac12$

thinking that the answer was $x>2$. But the answer turned out to be (-∞, 0) ∪ (2, +∞). Why is the answer in this form, and how do you get it?

Comment: Try naming a number in the "surprising" interval $(-\infty,0)$, and plugging into the inequality to see if indeed it holds.  This will give you the hint you need.

Comment: Have you ever seen a graph of [$y=\frac{1}{x}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D1%2Fx)?  Notice that when $x$ is negative, the left hand side is negative and is therefore indeed less than $\frac{1}{2}$.  As for a longer explanation, if you tried to multiply both sides by two and multiply both sides by $x$, you need to take into account the fact that the direction of the inequality **changes** when multiplying by a negative number, so you must split into cases and consider each individually.

Comment: The first option definitely

Comment: Your approach is correct, but notice that the inequality is preserved upon taking $x>0$. However, we must also consider the case where $x<0$, right? If we are to consider all real values of $x$, this is a logical progression.

Comment: oops, can't believe that i didn't notice values for which x<0. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $x$ can be
negative as well as positive.

If $x > 0$,
then you get your
$x > 2$.

If $x < 0$,
then
$\frac1{x} < 0 < \frac12$
is true
for all negative $x$.

Answer (score 1):

One is bound to have to split into cases for this. If we are working only over positive $x$, then it is correct to take
$$\frac{1}x<\frac{1}2$$
and take the reciprocal of both sides to get
$$x>2$$
since the reciprocal reverses the order *on positive x* (or more generally, when both sides are of the same sign). This is probably what you did. If you'd noted the restriction to positive $x$, you could check out the case for negative $x$ and note that $\frac{1}x<0<2$ for any $x<0$, thus any $x<0$ suffices. This gives the answer.

Another way to go about it is to consider multiplying
$$\frac{1}x<\frac{1}2$$
by $2x$. If $x$ is positive, the order is preserved giving $2<x$. If $x$ is negative, the order is reversed, giving $2>x$, which is is satisfied for all negative $x$, thus we know that a positive $x$ greater than $2$ satisfies the equation, as well as all negative $x$. This is, again, the given answer.